# html2pdf not able to download the mapbox map

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html2canvas, html2pdf

html2pdf is not able to download the mapbox map, it downloads the rest of the text content from webpage along with styles.

Below is the JS code:

```
document.getElementById("download")
.addEventListener("click", () => {


  HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = function(origFn) {
    return function(type, attribs) {
    attribs = attribs || {};
    attribs.preserveDrawingBuffer = true;
    return origFn.call(this, type, attribs);
    
    };
    }(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext);
    

    const mapDownload = this.document.getElementById("mapDownload");
    console.log(window);
    var opt = {
        margin: 1,
        filename: 'myfile.pdf',
        image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
        html2canvas: { scale: 2, useCORS: true, },
        jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'landscape' }
    };
    html2pdf().from(mapDownload).set(opt).save();
})
```

screenshot of the webpage:
[image: This is the image of the webpage with map]

Screenshot of PDF that gets downloaded:
[image: PDF Downloaded]

Stuck on this for so long, help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty convinced this is why mapbox probably doesn't keep a buffer around when drawing. As far as I know they expose no way of retrieving the image (like how threeJS by default doesn't keep the rendering buffer either, so you can't export them unless explicitly defined)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @somethinghere. What do you mean by explicitly defined? is it something that mapbox has to take care of to allow the export?

Comment: In WebGL, there is the option to keep the buffer around or not - its a memory optimisation thing. Because of this, exporting the actual contents isn't exactly possible because it's written on the fly. I know threejs does it with `preserveDrawingBuffer` in the renderer, so I'm assuming mapbox uses the same technique to prevent you from easily lifting their tiles from their API?

Comment: Got it, Thank you @somethinghere. Btw, as you suggested just a link of code snippet worked: preserveDrawingBuffer: true

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'ZipMapusa',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
        zoom: 3.5,
        maxZoom: 10,
        scrollZoom: true,
        maxBounds: bounds,
        center: [-96.3558753, 36.78],
        preserveDrawingBuffer: true,
      });

Comment: Nice, I'll be honest, I looked at the threeJS implementation and not the mapbox one (quite surprised its the exact same wording but I guess it just exposes the same webGL option). Good this worked!